# No main manifest attribute in jar, IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

This question has been asked many times before, but I have tried every solution and none of them worked for me.

I am trying to build a simple, single-module .jar program using IntelliJ and Gradle. Here is my build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = ...
version = ...

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.2.3")
    implementation("jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:2.1.0")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.9.0")
    implementation("commons-net:commons-net:3.8.0")
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30")

    val slf4jVersion = "2.0.3"
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:$slf4jVersion")

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1")
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = ...
        attributes["Class-Path"] = configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().asPath
    }

//    from(configurations.compileClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) })
}

tasks.getByName<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have the `from(configurations...)` line commented out now, but either way it wasn't working.

The issue is that when I try to build a .jar file and run it (in the terminal), I simply get the error:

`no main manifest attribute, in ...jar`

I have created dozens of different artifacts for this, trying different ways of arranging it. I've tried having my META-INF folder in resources or src/main. I've tried adding the contents of resources, META-INF, and the manifest itself to the jar file directly in the artifacts menu of project structure, but to no avail.

I'm at the end of my rope. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share a sample project on GitHub to get help with your configuration. There are too many factors that can affect it and we can spend a lot of time guessing what exactly is wrong with your configuration. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Why you have:

```
   attributes["Main-Class"] = ...
```

do you have actual Main-Class there instead of these three dots "..."?